# Which Giraph I/O format can be used for property graph?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, titan, tinkerpop, giraph

There are several built-in input output format in Giraph, but all those formats support only numerical ids & value.

- So is there a way to process property graph such that both vertices & edges can have multiple key & values or anything close? I'm specifically interested in **whether edge can have attributes** like `timeCreated` or `type`.
- Also, is there some convention to use only numerical ids & data for faster processing? Specifically, is the property graph from graph database usually filtered to have only ids & value before batch processing using Giraph?

Answer (score 1):

At least from Neo4j you can use the csv export of node- and relationship-id's to generate the data for giraph.

You can use something like this:

http://neo4j.com/blog/export-csv-from-neo4j-curl-cypher-jq/

and you can use neo4j-import to import that csv data, or LOAD CSV for more advanced structural updates.

Comment: Sure, I can load node & relationship **ids** from any graph database to Giraph using Tinkerpop's gremlin too. But I'm really interested in batch processing a property graph, i.e. use the properties of both nodes & edges, using Giraph.